# 10個の数値を入力しながら表示するプログラムを作りたい

Tags: c

10個の数値を入力しながら表示するプログラムを作りたいのですが

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)

{
int a[10],i;
for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
{
scanf("%d",&a[i])
printf("%d\n",a[i]);
}
return(0);
```

となっているのですが、どこを訂正すればよいのでしょうか？
教えていただけると嬉しいです。

Comment: `scanf`の直後にそのアレイ要素を出力します。

Comment: あと `a[10]` に書き込んでいるのでバグっていますね

Comment: すいません。よくわかりません。

Comment: 「作りたいプログラム」に対して、現状のプログラムでは「どんな問題があるのか」の説明が必要な気がします。

Comment: 編集後の現在のプログラムだと「入力しながら表示する」は達成できているはずっス（他の問題はあるけど）こんな簡単なプログラムでもあなたの意図しない動きをする要素はいっぱい指摘できますので「何が気に入らない（＝どんな問題があるのか）」を読者に説明してください。全部指摘するとすごい分量になっちゃうので。

Answer (score 0):

> int a[10];

として宣言されている配列のアクセスできる範囲は、
a[0] ～ a[9] までの１０個に限られます。

あなたのコードではこれに則っていませんね。

Answer (score 0):

閉じ括弧 `}` が１つ不足しているのでそれを補ったならコンパイル・実行できるようになります。で、それ以外の問題点としては既にコメント/回答ある通り `a[10]` という要素は存在しませんので

`for (i=1; i<=10; i++)`  を
`for (i=0; i<10; i++)`  にすれば「入力しながら表示する」は正しく達成できます。
（ `printf("a[%d]=%d\n", i, a[i]);` などのほうが混乱を招かないかもしれないです）

が：

- Visual Studio (っつか `MSVC`) では `scanf` に対して warning C4996 が発生する
- 誤って非数値文字 (`a` とか `.` とか) を入力すると以下全部失敗する
- `scanf()` はバッファリングを行う関係で１行で複数要素を読み取れてしまう
- １行につき１数値だけ読みたいなら違う方策が必要
などなど「プログラマが勝手に期待しているのと違う動作」をする要因はいくつも思いつきます。「正しいプログラム」であっても「設計者の意図と違う動作をする」ことは普通にあり、あなたが気に入らない動作がどこなのかは説明してもらわないと一般論で終わってしまうでしょう。